# Derived data type pointer?

Tags: pointers, types, fortran

I'm trying to convert some C code to Fortran 90. Is there a way in Fortran to define a derived data type which is a pointer? The code below is an example of what I'm talking about.

```
typedef struct _rkmatrix rkmatrix;
typedef rkmatrix *prkmatrix;
```

The struct `_rkmatrix` is defined outside this snippet of code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Example declarations for a linked list:

```
type MyCustom_type
   real :: value
   type (MyCustom_type), pointer :: next => null ()
end type MyCustom_type

type (MyCustom_type), pointer :: Head_of_List
```